# How do you apply a theme with powershell in 2013?

Tags: 2013, powershell, theme

I'm writing a powershell script that creates a number of site collections. I want to programmatically set the composed look to "Sea Monster".

Through the web UI I go to Site Settings > "Change the look" and click on "Sea Monster".

Is there a way to do this with powershell? Are these "considered composed" looks or "themes"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, a **Composed Look** is the combination of following::

- Master Pages
- CSS
- Color palettes
- Font palettes
- Background image

[image]

Hence can easily be set via PowerShell

```
$themeName = "Sea Monster"
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://sp2013/"    
foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs) 
{ 
      $SPWeb.allowunsafeupdates = $true
      $fontSchemeUrl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme003.spfont"
      $themeurl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette005.spcolor"
      $imageUrl = $SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/images/image_bg005.jpg"
      $SPWeb.ApplyTheme($themeUrl, $fontSchemeUrl, $imageUrl, $true);
      Write-Host "Set" $themeName "at :" $SPWeb.Title "(" $SPWeb.Url ")" 
      $SPWeb.Update()
      $SPWeb.allowunsafeupdates = $false
      $SPWeb.Dispose()
}  
$SPSite.Dispose()
```

Happy ShareComposing :)

Comment: You made a mistake. Try by replace all the $SPSite by $Site ;)

Comment: Doesn't matter it's a variable name ;)

Comment: Hi Falak, Can you tell me how to pass the iamge and font url as null.. ?

Comment: Have you tried passing "" or `$null`as a null value?

Comment: FalakMahmood I have tried with both, still getting errors. Thanks for the reply. @variable, did you find a workaround ?

Comment: What kind of error you're getting?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431037.aspx

Check the documentation your version of `$SPWeb.ApplyTheme` no longer works for SharePoint 2013

This is what I've got to work so far:

```
$web=Get-SPWeb http://intranet.contoso.com
$file=$web.GetFile($web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette005.spcolor")
$theme=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPTheme]::Open("AnyNameYouWanttoCallIt", $file)
$theme.ApplyTo($web, $false)
$web.Dispose()
```

If anyone knows how to determine the current theme--I'd like to know?

Comment: Good answer there. I figured out a way to get the existing Theme. Just do a $web.ThemedCssFolderUrl. That will point you to a Theme folder (Normally /_theme/1) which is the rendered out Theme. I.E, it will have your master page, SPCOLOR etc in it.

Answer (score 3):

Note everyone - `SPWeb.ApplyTheme` is not obsolete - only the method with the signature `ApplyTheme(string)` - that was for applying a theme by passing only the theme name. The method `SPWeb.ApplyTheme(String, String, String, Boolean)` is perfectly fine (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj251358(v=office.15).aspx). That allows you to specify the URLs for the color palette file, the font file, the background image (can be null if no image needed), and a boolean to specify whether (assuming this is a sub-web) the generated theme files should go into the root web.

Hope this helps clean up google results on the subject! - Had me quite worried for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

[This technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23510.sharepoint-2013-deploy-and-apply-theme-to-sharepoint-sites-with-powershell.aspx) has a great script for managing themes across site collections.

> This is complete PowerShell snippet which you can use to deploy and
>   apply theme to your environment. I have not tested it for ‘My Sites’
>   but it should work practically.

Script:

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
[xml]$inputfile = Get-Content C:\Data\theme\ThemeScriptInput.xml

$ColorFilePartUrl = "/_catalogs/theme/15/";
$FontFilePartUrl = "/_catalogs/theme/15/";
$MasterPagePartUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/";

foreach( $site in $inputfile.SiteCollections.site)
{
    $siteurl = $site.url;
    $themeName = $site.theme;
    $colorfile = $site.colorfile;
    $fontfile = $site.fontfile;
    $masterpage = $site.masterpage;
    $colorshemeFilePath = $site.colorFilePath;
    $colorfontFilePath = $site.fontFilePath;
    $IsfilesToUpload = $site.filesToUpload;

    Write-Host "$siteurl + " :: " + $themeName + " :: " + $colorfile + " :: " + $fontfile + " :: " + $masterpage";

    $site = Get-SPSite $siteurl;
    $rootweb = $site.RootWeb;

    if($IsfilesToUpload -eq "true")
    {
        #region Upload theme files to the root web gallery      

        $colorSchemeBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($colorshemeFilePath);
        $fontSchemeBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($colorfontFilePath);

        $rootweb.allowunsafeupdates = $true;
        $themeList = $rootweb.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::ThemeCatalog);
        $folder = $themeList.RootFolder.SubFolders["15"];
        $folder.Files.Add($colorfile,$colorSchemeBytes,$true);
        $folder.Files.Add($fontfile,$fontSchemeBytes, $true);
        $rootweb.allowunsafeupdates = $false;
        #endregion
    }

    $colorfile=$site.AllWebs[0].GetFile("$siteurl$ColorFilePartUrl$colorfile");
    $fontfile=$site.AllWebs[0].GetFile("$siteurl$FontFilePartUrl$fontfile");

    foreach ($Web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
       Write-Host "processing: " $Web.Title;
       $Web.allowunsafeupdates = $true;
       $relativeUrl = $Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
       $spList = $Web.GetCatalog([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DesignCatalog);

       #region Add New theme to the Composed Looks gallery

       $SPQuery1 =  New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
       $SPQuery1.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name'/><Value Type='Text'>$themeName</Value></Eq></Where>";
       $SPQuery1.RowLimit = 1;
       $SPQuery1.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>";
       $SPQuery1.ViewFieldsOnly = $true;

       $spListItems1 = $spList.GetItems($SPQuery1);


       if($spListItems1.Count -eq 0)
       {        

       $newThemeItem = $spList.AddItem();

       $newThemeItem["Name"] = $themeName;
       $newThemeItem["Title"] = $themeName;
       $newThemeItem["MasterPageUrl"] =  "$relativeUrl$MasterPagePartUrl$masterpage";#$Web.MasterUrl;
       $newThemeItem["ThemeUrl"] = "$ColorFilePartUrl$colorfile";
       $newThemeItem["FontSchemeUrl"] = "$FontFilePartUrl$fontfile";
       $newThemeItem["DisplayOrder"] = 121;
       $newThemeItem.Update();

       }
       #endregion

       #region Set the theme


        $theme=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPTheme]::Open($themeName, $colorfile);
        Write-Host $theme.Name "to" $Web.Title;
        $theme.ApplyTo($Web, $false);



       #endregion

       #region Set applied theme as current theme             

       $SPQuery =  New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
       $SPQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Eq></Where>";
       $SPQuery.RowLimit = 1;
       $SPQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='DisplayOrder'/>";
       $SPQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true;

       $spListItems = $spList.GetItems($SPQuery);


       if($spListItems.Count -eq 1)
       {
            $spListItems[0].Delete();
       }

       $currentThemeItem = $spList.AddItem();

       $currentThemeItem["Name"] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPResource]::GetString([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Strings]::DesignGalleryCurrentItemName);
       $currentThemeItem["Title"] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPResource]::GetString([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Strings]::DesignGalleryCurrentItemName);
       $currentThemeItem["MasterPageUrl"] = "$relativeUrl$MasterPagePartUrl$masterpage";#$Web.MasterUrl;
       $currentThemeItem["ThemeUrl"] = "$ColorFilePartUrl$colorfile";
       $currentThemeItem["FontSchemeUrl"] = "$FontFilePartUrl$fontfile";
       $currentThemeItem["DisplayOrder"] = 0;
       $currentThemeItem.Update();

       #endregion

       $Web.allowunsafeupdates = $false;
       Write-Host "Set" $theme.Name "theme to :" $Web.Title "(" $Web.Url ")" ;
    }

}
```

Config File

```
<SiteCollections>
  <site>
    <url>http://local/sites/MyBlog/url>
    <theme>Collaboration</theme>
   <filesToUpload>false</filesToUpload>
    <colorFilePath>C:\theme\collaborationcolor.spcolor</colorFilePath>
    <fontFilePath>C:\theme\collaborationfontscheme.spfont</fontFilePath>
    <colorfile>collaborationcolor.spcolor</colorfile>
   <fontfile>collaborationfontscheme.spfont</fontfile>
    <masterpage>seattle.master</masterpage>
  </site>
  <site>
    <url>http://local</url>
    <theme>Collaboration</theme>
    <filesToUpload>true</filesToUpload>
    <colorFilePath>C:\theme\collaborationcolor.spcolor</colorFilePath>
    <fontFilePath>C:\theme\collaborationfontscheme.spfont</fontFilePath>
    <colorfile>collaborationcolor.spcolor</colorfile>
    <fontfile>collaborationfontscheme.spfont</fontfile>
    <masterpage>seattle.master</masterpage>
  </site>
</SiteCollections>
```